# How to replace specific key elements in array with elements of another array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have an array object of variable length and i want to replace specific key elements of whole array with another array object which is also of variable length. I have tried different array methods but i am stuck at this one. I have 6 months of programming experience.

My code is:

```js
a = [
 { id: 1, name: "Alex", qty: 6, prodCode: 1321 }, 
 { id: 2, name: "carry", qty: 2, prodCode: 1641 }, 
 { id: 1, name: "manuel", qty: 7, prodCode: 1754 },
.....]

b= [{qty:5},{qty:9},{qty:2},...]
a.length===b.length
```

Result should be like:

```js
[
  { id: 1, name: "Alex", qty: 5, prodCode: 1321 }, 
  { id: 2, name: "carry", qty: 9, prodCode: 1641 }, 
  { id: 1, name: "manuel", qty: 2, prodCode: 1754 },
.....]
```

Comment: You say the arrays are of variable length, but can we assume `a.length === b.length`?

Comment: Yes a.length===b.length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, this is what needs to be done

```
for( let index = 0; index < objectArray.length; index++ ){

   objectArray[index].qty = qtys[index].qty;

}
```

You can use the Browser's js console to understand where each value resides in a JSON Object and how to get a value from it.

For example, run this in the console after initializing the objectArray

```
objectArray[0].qty // This will give qty of the first object in the array
```

You can use this to navigate inside a complicated object

Answer (score 3):

If I understand it well, you can try this:

```
a.forEach((itemA, index) => {
    itemA.qty = b[index].qty
});
```

Hope it helps you.